# Mysema QueryDSL JPAQuery for SQL groupby clause and order by

Tags: jpa-2.0, querydsl

I have Items class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Items")
Class Items{
    @ID
    private long id;
    private String upc;
    private long itemNo;
    private int qty;
   -----
}
```

I need to make below sql statement from JPAQuery of QueryDSL.

```
select itemNo, upc, count(*) t from Items group by ITEM_NO, UPC order by t;
```

**QueryDSL sample needs modification for order by clause**:

```
QItems items = QItems.items;
query.from(items)
.groupBy(items.itemNo,items.upc)
.orderby(<Dont Know How to sort on count>).list(items.itemNo,items.upc,items.count());
```

Need help to draft this query properly?

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
NumberPath<Long> count = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "c");
QItems items = QItems.items;
query.from(items)
    .groupBy(items.itemNo,items.upc)
    .orderby(count.asc())
    .list(items.itemNo,items.upc,items.count().as(count));
```

Comment: In my case:
NumberPath<Long> aliasCount = Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "user.userId");

query(user).groupByaliasCount).orderBy(aliasCount.count().desc()).limit(limit);

Also did the trick!!

Comment: just avoid naming your alias as "count" => `Expressions.numberPath(Long.class, "count")` it has gave me `expecting OPEN, found 'desc'` because `count` is reserved word in sql